# Is this feasible: Open multiple pairs of PDF files, select text, paste each page separately into a new cell of a two-column Word file

Tags: batch, copy-paste

There are hundreds of PDF files located in different folders. The paths of the files that need to be handled are in an Excel file (or in a text file). The algorithm is as follows:

Take the address of each pair of PDF files from a source file, open the first PDF, select all in the first page, copy, create a Word file and paste it into the left column of the two-column table. Do it for every page of the PDF file. Then do the same with the second PDF file of the pair, pasting each page into the right column (or, if possible, paste all pages at one, but each page must occupy a separate cell). Close and save the Word file  (with a name based on the name of the PDF file) . Repeat with the next pair of PDF files.

Is this even possible to write a reasonably simple script that would do this?

Comment: It depends on many factors. How were the pdfs created? Can text be copied out of them directly or does an OCR process need to run on them? But, most importantly, what have you tried. We aren't a script a script writing service here. Once you've started something and then come up against some difficulty you are unable to get past, we are happy to help you there, but asking us to build an entire solution isn't the sort of thing we do.

Comment: The problem is I don't even know what programming language to use. So my question is in what direction I should look for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this even possible to write a reasonably simple script that would do this?

This would likely depend on two factors:

1. Do the PDFs contain actual text or are they images of text compiled into a PDF (needing optical character recognition [OCR])?
2. What is your definition of "reasonably simple"?

I would think this might be a longer script, even if it wasn't difficult to produce.

As a small suggestion, I might possibly look into using [Python](https://www.python.org/) for much (if not all) of this task. Python has third-party modules particularly dealing with PDFs and Word that could be potentially useful. Python also has the ability to run other command-line programs through its `subprocess` module as well.

That said, there is no reason that you couldn't potentially use a variety of tools and tie them together via scripting  (e.g. with batch, Python or in combination with any other scripting/programming language).

Comment: PDFs are perfectly copyable. By reasonably simple I mean that it won't take days of coding. Thank you for directing me to Python. That may be valuable.